# What will happen if we don't use DeleteObject

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

We had to use the `DeleteObject` function for deleting a GDI object.

But what will happen if we don't delete a GDI pen which was created through the `CreatePen` function?

Comment: Then, you leak resources.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Task Manager
2. Go to the Details tab (or Processes tab in Windows 7 and earlier).
3. Show the "GDI Objects" column
4. Run your process without deleting GDI objects, preferably in a tight-loop
5. Observe your process' GDI object count will continuously increase
6. Eventually you'll hit [GDI object limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx). Either the per-process limit (10,000 in Windows 8.1) or the session limit of the GDI object limit of 65,535
7. Then you'll start seeing weird visual artifacts and glitches as things just aren't drawn correctly, not just in your process, but other processes also using GDI (especially Internet Explorer 8 or earlier which is particularly GDI-heavy)
8. Assuming your process doesn't crash, you'll see why you should clean-up your GDI objects :)

Comment: It was big problem in older Win, specially most applications was created in un-safe enthronements, i.e raw Win API

Answer (score 0):

> But what will happen if we don't delete a GDI pen which was created through the CreatePen function?

Then the resources associated with the resource won't be freed.
You get a memory leak.

Comment: Reasorce leak is not only memory leak.